# Roslaunch with supervisor

Tags: roslaunch, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am using [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/)  and roslaunch in order to start my turtlebot. Running the launch file on the robot directly works fine... but when I try to run it using supervisor it cannot locate the nodes.

After asking around and looking for answers on the internet I found that the problem could lie on the setup of my environment variables.
I solved many of the first problems by setting up the PYTHON_PATH and ROS_PACKAGE_PATH environment variables  in my supervisor configuration file...but  I still get these errors on my error.log file:

```
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [map_server/map_server]: can't locate node [map_server] in package [map_server]

ERROR: cannot launch node of type [map_server/map_server]: can't locate node [map_server] in package [map_server]

ERROR: cannot launch node of type [rosbridge_server/rosbridge_websocket]: can't locate node [rosbridge_websocket] in  package [rosbridge_server] 

ERROR: cannot launch node of type [rosapi/rosapi_node]: can't locate node [rosapi_node] in package [rosapi] Unhandled exception in thread started by sys.excepthook is missing lost sys.stderr
```

Does anyone have experience working with supervisor and ROS and could help me with this problem?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261158/roslaunch-with-supervisor/) by [Irod](https://answers.ros.org/users/27882/irod/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-05-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You also need to set CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH (so that ROS can find nodes built with catkin), LD_LIBRARY_PATH (so that binaries can find their dynamic libraries) and maybe a few other environment variables too.

If possible, it would be better to have supervisord source the `setup.bash` or `setup.sh` file for your ROS workspace. This will probably be easier than setting the environment variables manually, and it will make sure that you don't accidentally forget to set anything.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-05-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Irod](https://answers.ros.org/users/27882/irod/) on 2017-05-09**:
Thanks for the answer. I solved it by setting the environment variables manually...for now, because I still don't know how to source the setup.bash or setup.sh file with supervisord and I agree that would be better.